# Python - Sarima/Sarimax - creation of an output table for multiple predictions

Tags: python, auto, arima, sarimax

I'm currently working on a project and I'm not quite sure how to best implement the next step, so I'd appreciate suggestions and feedback.

In my data a certain date can occur several times, because I forecast the sales by zipcode.
[Example of the data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJ5Zd.png)
The background to this is that I want to add weather to the zipcodes. To check afterwards if different weather parameters make a forecast of my models (SARIMA/SARIMAX) better.
Afterwards I would like to have an output in a table, in which to all Zipcodes the RMSE of the Prediction is stored. It would also be good if parameters were selected for this by auto_arima.

I would then compare these between SARIMA and SARIMAX, so that I can check how much % of the predictions have become better with external data.

Currently the data is in a table with over 60 zipcodes. Does anyone have an idea or a function that I can use to create multiple modells (per zipcode with selected parameters) and the table?

I have now read something about pyramid, but I'm not quite sure if that is the right package, in any case I could not find a similar example.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Each zip code has its own time series. If you have 60 zip codes then you might need to create 60 models, one for each time series. That is a lot of effort.
The easiest way would be something like this:

You can automate this with pyramid. There is a function `auto_arima()` that tries to find the best possible set of parameters for ARIMA. You can split your dataframe by zip codes. Then you can create a loop over all dataframes. Inside the loop you first run `auto_arima()` to find the best possible parameters:

```
from pmdarima.arima import auto_arima

auto_arima_model = auto_arima(y=endogenous_variable,
                              x=exogenous_variable, #only required if exog data is used
                              seasonal=True,
                              m=7, #seasonality
                              information_criterion="aic",
                              trace=True)
```

`auto_arima` can not detect if your data is stationary or not, so you need to find that out yourself. Check the documentation:

https://alkaline-ml.com/pmdarima/modules/generated/pmdarima.arima.auto_arima.html

Then you create a model (e.g. in statsmodels, auto_arima() also returns a model but it does not have as many functionalities as statsmodels):

```
from statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax import SARIMAX

model = SARIMAX(endog=endogenous_variable,
                exog=exogenous_variable, #only required if exog data is used
                order=auto_arima_model.order,
                seasonal_order=auto_arima_model.seasonal_order).fit()
```

https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax.SARIMAX.html

Then you can make your predictions and add them to tables or whatever you want to do with that. You can also implement this in a pipeline. You should keep in mind that `auto_arima()` is a good function but not perfect, the models will probably not be the very best.

Comment: Thanks for you feedback. Then i will try to split the set and create multiple predictions. Too bad that there is no better way.